# Where can I ask what the name for an object in an image is?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have an image of a type of hat in the real world, but I don't know what it's called. Where can I ask what the name for this kind of hat is?

My first thought was the [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) tag on English Language and Usage, but according to that tag's info:

> To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE DEMONSTRATING HOW THE WORD WOULD BE USED.

which means that it has to be about a word, not about "what kind of object is this?".

Where can I ask what the name for an object in an image is?

Comment: What kind of object is it? Meaning... do you know what sort of thing it is or is it a complete mystery?

Comment: @Catija It's a hat, but I don't know what kind of hat it is.

Comment: If there's no SE site for this, you could try your luck at [The Wolfram Language Image Identification Project](https://www.imageidentify.com/), where you just have to upload an image and the server tries to identify it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll be fine on ELU if you use the [image-identification](/questions/tagged/image-identification) tag along with the SWR tag.

Follow the example of this question:

[Is there a term for this piece of hair?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272591/is-there-a-term-for-this-piece-of-hair)

Which, I believe, fits what you're trying to ask.

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Thanks!